# Find a value in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So my collection is something like:

```
[
    {"name": "one", "jobs": ["1","2","3","4","5"]},
    {"name": "two", "jobs": ["6","7","8","9","10"]},
    {"name": "three", "jobs": ["11","12","13","14","15"]},
]
```

And I want to create a query to find the name based on the value from `jobs`. So if `jobs=2`, the name should be `one`; if  `jobs=9`, the name should be `two`; if `jobs=13`, the name should be `three`. What do i put in the 
`db.collection.find({ ?? })`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just complementing the other answer, if you wanna search from a range of jobs, you can do something like:

```
db.collection.find({jobs:{$in:["13","14"]}},{name:1})
```

If you want to get a **slice** of this array, you can use the slice operator. It takes two parameters: The first is the initial index and the second is the number of elements after this index. Here's an example:

```
db.tasks.find({jobs:{$in:["13","14"]}},{name:1,jobs:{$slice : [0,2]}})
```

This will take **two** elements from the index [0] of the array.

Comment: This doesn't work. The name is not returned. And what do i do if I want to return the job number too? thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you run the correct code? the {name:1} means to put the name. If you want to return the name and all the jobs you can just do the query without the second part like `db.collection.find({jobs:{$in:["1","2"]}})` or add the jobs to the projection `db.collection.find({...},{name:1,jobs:1})`

Comment: Thanks. I was making a type. Thanks. I can get all the values now.

Comment: Another thing please, what if the key, `name` is an array with some values, say 20 values and updating regularly. And I want to list the latest 5 values from that array.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this.

The below query will select all rows where the `jobs` array has the element with value `"3"` and project the `name` field.

```
db.collection.find({jobs:"3"},{name:1})
```

More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#array-element-equals-a-value

Comment: This works. But what if i want to find 2 names. I tried `{jobs:"2" || jobs:"9" }`. thanks. Also if I want to return everything from that value, not just the `name` what do i do? MySQ equivalent to `SELECT *`

Comment: You are welcome. For first part try {$or: [{jobs:"2"}, {jobs:"9"}]}. For second part get rid of {name:1}.