# slice in array not working?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

This is my mongoose collection data:

```
      {
           "ShopId" : "439",
           "productName" : "veg",
           "productCategory" : "meals",
           "mrp" : "38 "

        },
        { 
        "ShopId" : "439",
           "productName" : "non-veg",
           "productCategory" : "meals",
           "mrp" : "380 "
           },{....}
```

**Query**

```
    db.getCollection('ProductDetails').aggregate(
    [{ "$match": { "ShopId": "439" } },{"$group": {"_id": "$productCategory", "count": { "$sum": 1 }, 
    "products": {"$push":{"productname": "$productName"}}}},
    {"$group": {"_id": null, "productList": {"$push": {"categoryname": "$_id", "productcount": "$count",
        "products": "$products"}}}},{$project:{products:{$slice:["$productList.products",2]}}}])
```

**Output:**

```
    {
    "_id" : null,
    "productList" : [ 
        {
           "categoryname" : "meals",
            "productcount" : 8.0,
            "products" : [ 
                {
                    "productname" : "non veg"
                }, 
                {
                    "productname" : "veg"
                }, 
                {
                    "productname" : "c"
                }, 
                {
                    "productname" : "d"
                }, 
                {
                    "productname" : "df"
                }, 
                {
                    "productname" : "dfr"
                }, 
                {
                    "productname" : "qe"
                }, 
                {
                    "productname" : "as"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**expected output**:

I want to limit the number of products to 2.But instead of that all products are displaying.

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "productList" : [ 
        {
           "categoryname" : "meals",
            "productcount" : 8.0,
            "products" : [ 
                {
                    "productname" : "non veg"
                }, 
                {
                    "productname" : "veg"
                } 
               ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `$project` stage with below.

```
{$project:{products:{$slice:[{$arrayElemAt:["$productList.products", 0]},2]}}}
```

Your products is array of arrays.

```
"products": [
  [{
    "productname": "veg"
  }, {
    "productname": "non-veg"
  }]
]
```

`$arrayElemAt` with `0` will pick the inner array and you can use `$slice` to limit the products.

Comment: but category name and product count are not showing in result

Comment: you have to add them to the $project stage

Comment: whether i need to put 1 for that fields in $project?

Comment: Something like `"categoryname":"productList.categoryname"`

Comment: then it becomes 2 arrays one for productlist and other for product, what should do to put the product array inside product list array

Comment: I'll try to take a look when I have little bit time. What is your mongo server version ?

Comment: mongo db version - 3.4.2    mongoose -4.7.6

Comment: Okay try replacing you `$project` stage with `{$addFields:{"productList.products":{$slice:[{$arrayElemAt:["$productList.products", 0]},2]}}}` and see if it helps.

Comment: no didnt,worked..fieldname donot start with '$' is showing as error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136465/discussion-between-veeram-and-midhun-k).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using the `$slice` function wrong: As I mentioned in this post:

[Find a value in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404686/find-a-value-in-array/42405144#42405144)

The slice function takes two parameters: The first is the initial index and the second is the number of elements after this index. Here's an example:

db.collection.find({},{_id:0,products:{$slice : [0,2]})

This will take two elements from the index [0] of the array. Hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was using it with JavaScript's method instead